# Uncaught TypeError: tasks.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Here is a function of a simple todo list where I want to add my tasks in Local Storage. Then, I got stuck in this problem...

```
function storeTaskInLocalStorage(task){
    let tasks 
    if(localStorage.getItem('tasks') === null){
        tasks = []
    } else {
        tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"))
    }
    tasks.push(task)

    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks))
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in this function ? Also, make sure you do not overwrite the `tasks` in `localStorage` from other code.

Comment: Use a debugger and step through the code line by line and see what `tasks` is before `push` is called.

Comment: my guess is tasks in localstorage is not an array? simple console.log can confirm it

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   function storeTaskInLocalStorage(task){
    let tasks =[];
    if(localStorage.getItem('tasks') !== null){
        
        tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"))
    }
    tasks.push(task)

    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks))
}
```

Comment: It's different in that `let` defines an array.